Assign to an expression
I'm learning Rust so getting to grips with mutable and non-mutable.  I've copied code from several projects and it works well.
This is the ode_solver function for a two-pool compartmental model.  My problem is I'm attempting to update the value of y[2] at each iteration, and yet the specification of the y state variable vector is immutable.  The values of y[0] and y[1] get added correctly (concatenated?) at each iteration, and what I want to do is concatenate a new value of y[2] = y[0] + y[1].
I tried changing the system specification from y: &State to y: &mut State but the ode_solver crate doesn't accept that. Is there a simple way to calculate the value to go into y[2] and then write it there?
Not surprisingly, the error message I'm getting is:
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side of assignment
80 |     &y[2] = y[0] + y[1];
   |     ----- ^
   |     |
   |     cannot assign to this expression

impl ode_solvers::System<f64, State> for TwoPool {
    fn system(&self, _: Time, y: &State, dy: &mut State) {
        let con_a = y[0] / SA;
        let con_b = y[1] / SB;

        let FAB = VAB / (1.0 + (KAB / con_a));
        let FBA = VBA / (1.0 + (KBA / con_b));
        let FBO = VBO / (1.0 + (KBO / con_b));

        dy[0] = FOA + FBA - FAB;
        dy[1] = FAB - FBA - FBO;

        &y[2] = y[0] + y[1];

        println!("PoolSizes A={:.3}, B={:.3}, Tot={:.3}", y[0], y[1], y[2]);
    }
}


ode_solver specifically doesn't allow writing, as y is immutable

&y[2] becomes &(y[2]). & gets the location of a value. You can't change the location of a value via assignment. You should remove the &. It still won't work because y isn't mutable but at least you'll fix the syntax error

The syntax to assign is foo[index] = bar, but trait method is designed to prevent mutating the State. Can you mutate the state outside of system, wherever you're calling system(...)?

@BallpointBen, I probably can, will investigate that.

The signature of the trait method from the crate you are using clearly expects you to only read from y and write to dy. There is no way around this fact. You can either use a different crate, or you have to conform to this requirement. More importantly, even if you could somehow mutate y, it doesn't make sense at all - system is supposed to give the derivate at a point y, this is mathematically a pure function, how does one interpret the calculation of a derivative changing the input point?

@user2407038 Thx, and I'm sure you are correct.  This is a model of a biological system, so it would be useful to monitor the size of the total system as the simulation progresses.  So the total size at any specific time is y[0] + y[1], after dy, y[0], and y[1] have been calculated at each iteration.  Does this not make sense?

No, because the 2nd argument passed to the system function is not "the" point at some specific time, it's some particular point which the particular solver is interested in evaluating. It is likely a temporary variable which will be discarded soon after the call. for example, Some solvers evaluate in a box or a circle within some distance of a starting point, more elaborate solvers do more elaborate evaluations. If you want to store some extra metadata at each simulation step, I think you will have to write your own solver, as well as your implementation of System
